# Magento 2 : Add Custom Fee to Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, paypal-express, extrafee

I develop custom extension which add custom fee to order based on payment method selection. Every thing working fine except `"Paypal Express Checkout"`.

When I select this method, it added custom fee into total fine and it show on checkout like this.

[image]

To pass this custom fee into paypal express checkout,
I do code like this.

app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="payment_cart_collect_items_and_amounts">
        <observer name="add_fee_to_paypal" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\AddFeeToPaypal" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And Observer file like this.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

class AddFeeToPaypal implements ObserverInterface
{
    public $checkout;

    public function __construct(Session $checkout)
    {
        $this->checkout = $checkout;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getCart();
        $quote = $this->checkout->getQuote();
        $address = $quote->getIsVirtual() ? $quote->getBillingAddress() : $quote->getShippingAddress();

        if ($fee = $address->getCustomFee())
        {
            $cart->addCustomItem('Paypal Payment Fee', 1, $fee);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

But is show me error like this.

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item
>   amounts do not match order amounts (#10413: Transaction refused
>   because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for
>   details).

[image]

How can I solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/manage-custom-amount-paypal-magento2/ This one I used and it's works fine for me please try  it

Comment: I try that as well, still it show same error.

Comment: on your this observer for paypal, try to add extra fee on order total as well and it will solve the purpose.

Comment: @John can you share code what you are trying to explain.